# Why RoamingSettings clears after app update?

Tags: windows-runtime

I using sample https://mytoolkit.svn.codeplex.com/svn/WinRT/Storage/ApplicationSettings.cs for manage my app settings.

Save settings **login** to roaming:

```
ApplicationSettings.SetSetting("login", "qwe123", true);
```

Read setting **login** from roaming:

```
ApplicationSettings.GetSetting<string>("login", true)
```

Why my roaming setting **login** is empty when app update?

For example in **app version 2.0.0.0** roaming setting **login= "qwe123"**, but when i update my app to version **3.0.0.0** roaming setting **login = ""**

Answer (score 1):

This is by design.  The path where the file data is stored includes the version number of your application.

Take a look at the [ApplicationData.SetVersionAsync() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.setversionasync.aspx), specifically intended to solve this problem.  Only use it when you can ensure that a new version of your program won't fall over when it reads the old data.

Comment: But how? in app v.2 i set SetVersionAsync in 1, when update app to v.3 ApplicationData.Current.Version = 0.

Comment: I am puzzled.  Why did you not mention in your question that you used SetVersionAsync() in your old code?  Or you didn't because you didn't hear about it until today?  In which case you should of course not expect the version of your old data to be set.